# How to prevent Android GreedoLayout Out-of-bounds exception?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

How do you prevent Greedo from accessing index which is out-of-bounds ?

The following is the stack trace:

--------- beginning of crash

> 12-28 17:19:22.338 8668-8668/com.pixerf.android E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                     Process: com.pixerf.android, PID: 8668
>                                                                     java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 56, Size: 56
>                                                                         at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:411)
>                                                                         at com.fivehundredpx.greedolayout.GreedoLayoutSizeCalculator.sizeForChildAtPosition(GreedoLayoutSizeCalculator.java:71)
>                                                                         at com.fivehundredpx.greedolayout.GreedoLayoutManager.sizeForChildAtPosition(GreedoLayoutManager.java:282)
>                                                                         at com.fivehundredpx.greedolayout.GreedoLayoutManager.preFillGrid(GreedoLayoutManager.java:206)
>                                                                         at com.fivehundredpx.greedolayout.GreedoLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(GreedoLayoutManager.java:122)
>                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3719)
>                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3436)
>                                                                         at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3988)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
>                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
>                                                                         at android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout.onLayout(SwipeRefreshLayout.java:611)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
>                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
>                                                                         at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1079)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
>                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
>                                                                         at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1769)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
>                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
>                                                                         at android.support.design.widget.HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.layoutChild(HeaderScrollingViewBehavior.java:132)
>                                                                         at android.support.design.widget.ViewOffsetBehavior.onLayoutChild(ViewOffsetBehavior.java:42)
>                                                                         at android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$ScrollingViewBehavior.onLayoutChild(AppBarLayout.java:1361)
>                                                                         at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:874)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
>                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
>                                                                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
>                                                                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
>                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
>                                                                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
>                                                                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
>                                                                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
>                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
>                                                                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
>                                                                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
>                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
>                                                                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1741)
>                                                                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1585)
>                                                                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1494)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
>                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
>                                                                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:323)
>                                                                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:261)
>                                                                         at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:724)
>                                                                         at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17523)
>                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5612)
>                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2342)
>                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2069)
>                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1246)
>                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6301)
>                                                                         at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:871)
>                                                                         at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:683)
>                                                                         at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:619)
>                                                                         at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:857)
>                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
>   12-28 17:19:22.339 8668-8668/com.pixerf.android E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
>                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
>                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)

Answer (score 0):

check your arraylist or array size and then do your tasks

```
if(arraylist.size()>0)
{
//do something 
}
```

Comment: Based on stacktrace, the array is not empty. In my example, there's paging involved. Crash happens inside GreedoLayout library.

Comment: is there any way to get the arraylist of that library? if yes then u may try to check size of that arraylist before having your tasks done